# Django Subscription

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, in-app-subscription, razorpay

[Razor pay dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Dr1.jpg)I am trying to implement the subscription feature in my Django website, and I am using Razor pay payment gateway. My payment method is working fine as the payment details are showing in Razor pay dashboard, but after successful payment, membership is not getting assigned to user based on purchased. Please help me out as I am stuck here, not getting proper solution when doing search.
I want to fix it, not getting any solution. Please help me out here.

```
#models.py
# Create a membership type model
class MembershipType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create a membership plan model
class MembershipPlan(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.ForeignKey(MembershipType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    features = RichTextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create a user membership model
class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership_plan = models.ForeignKey(MembershipPlan, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def activate(self, payment_id):
        # Set the payment id and end date based on the plan duration
        self.payment_id = payment_id
        self.end_date = self.start_date + timezone.timedelta(days=self.membership_plan.duration)
        self.save()

    def is_active(self):
        # Check if the current date is within the start and end date
        if self.start_date is None or self.end_date is None:
            return False
        return self.start_date <= timezone.now() <= self.end_date

#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:type_id>/', views.membership_home, name='membership_home'),
    path('checkout/<int:plan_id>/', views.membership_checkout, name='membership_checkout'),
    path("payment/", views.razorpay_payment_callback, name="razorpay_payment_callback"),

]

#views.py
@login_required
def membership_home(request, type_id):
    # Get the current user's membership or create a new one if none exists
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    # Get all the available membership types and plans
    membership_types = MembershipType.objects.all()
    membership_plans = MembershipPlan.objects.filter(membership_type_id=type_id)

    # Render the membership home template with the context data
    context = {
        'user_membership': user_membership,
        'membership_types': membership_types,
        'membership_plans': membership_plans,
    }
    return render(request, 'membership/pricing.html', context)


@login_required
def membership_checkout(request, plan_id):
    # Get the selected plan by its id or redirect to home if not found
    try:
        plan = MembershipPlan.objects.get(id=plan_id)
    except MembershipPlan.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('membership_home')


    # Get the current user's membership or create a new one if none exists
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    # Check if the user already has an active membership of the same plan and redirect to home if yes
    if user_membership.is_active() and user_membership.membership_plan == plan:
        return redirect('membership_home')

    client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZORPAY_KEY, settings.RAZORPAY_SECRET))

    # Create a razorpay order with the plan details and save the order id in the session
    order_amount = plan.price * 100 # convert to paisa
    order_currency = 'INR'
    order_receipt = f'{request.user.username}-{plan.name}'
    order_notes = {'plan_id': plan.id}
    order_data = {
        'amount': order_amount,
        'currency': order_currency,
        'receipt': order_receipt,
        'notes': order_notes,
        'payment_capture': 1
    }
    order = client.order.create(data=order_data)
    order_id = order['id']
    request.session['order_id'] = order_id


    # Render the membership checkout template with the context data
    context = {
        'plan': plan,
        'order_id': order_id,
        'order_amount': order_amount,
        'order_currency': order_currency,
        'razorpay_key': settings.RAZORPAY_KEY,
    }
    return render(request, 'membership/payment.html', context)

@csrf_exempt
def razorpay_payment_callback(request):
    # Get the order id and payment id from the request data
    order_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_order_id')
    payment_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_payment_id')

    # Verify the payment signature using the razorpay secret
    params_dict = {
        'razorpay_order_id': order_id,
        'razorpay_payment_id': payment_id,
        'razorpay_signature': request.POST.get('razorpay_signature')
    }
    try:
        client.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
        payment_verified = True
    except:
        payment_verified = False

    # Get the current user's membership or create a new one if none exists
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    # If the payment is verified, get the plan id from the order notes and activate the user's membership
    if payment_verified:
        order = client.order.fetch(order_id)
        plan_id = order['notes']['plan_id']
        plan = MembershipPlan.objects.get(id=plan_id)
        user_membership.membership_plan = plan
        user_membership.activate(payment_id)

    # Render the membership payment template with the context data
    context = {
        'payment_verified': payment_verified,
        'user_membership': user_membership,
    }
    return render(request, 'membership/thank_you.html', context)



HTML TEMPLATE

{% block content %}
<!-- ============================ Page Title Start================================== -->
<div class="page-title">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

        <h2 class="ipt-title">Payment Methode</h2>
        <span class="ipn-subtitle">Pay your payment</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============================ Page Title End ================================== -->

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'membership_checkout' plan.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        "key": "{{ razorpay_key }}", // Replace with your Razorpay Key
        "amount": "{{ order_amount }}", // Replace with the payment amount in paisa (e.g., 1000 for ₹10.00)
        "name": "Rent House",
        "description": "Membership Payment",
        "image": "{% static 'assets/img/logo.png' %}", // Replace with your logo URL
        "order_id": "{{order_id}}",
        "handler": function (response) {
            // Handle the successful payment response here
            alert("Payment successful. Payment ID: " + response.razorpay_payment_id);
            // Typically, you would send the response to your server for verification
            // Redirect the user to a success page
            window.location.href = "{% url 'razorpay_payment_callback' %}"; // Replace with the actual URL of your success page
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "{{ request.user.name }}", // Replace with the user's name
            "email": "{{ request.user.email }}" // Replace with the user's email
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#2540a2" // Customize the theme color
        }
    };
    var rzp = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp.on('payment.failed', function (response){
            // Handle payment failure here
            alert("Payment failed. Error description: " + response.error.description);
        });
    rzp.open();
</script>

  </form>

  </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```